# react redux mapStateToProps - correct props not making it to the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component `OnePayrunGridContainer` which is wrapped in react-redux's `connect` Component.

There are two distinct async actions that update the redux store -

1. `FETCH_PAYRUN_TS_DETAILS` - to retrieve all the data after the component has loaded
2. `FETCH_TIMESLIP_DATA` - that updates the `state.timeslipInModal`

When there is an object in `timeslipInModal`, my render function displays it in a modal.

In the react tools in chrome and firefox, I can see the `console.log` output demonstrating that the redux store has updated, the `mapStateToProps` has been called, but when I inspect the component in the react console, the prop `timeslipInModal` remains `false` - it's initial value when the component was first rendered.

---

The [`react-redux` documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api#arguments) for `mapStateToProps` says -

> The new component will subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that any time the store is updated, `mapStateToProps` will be called.

which IS happening (I know this from a `console.log` in the `mapStateToProps`).

---

The documentation also says -

> The results of `mapStateToProps` must be a plain object, which will be merged into the component's props.

This part is what is NOT happening. I `console.log` the redux store `newState` just before I return it - and I can see the same output in the console when I have the `axios` debug feature turned on.

---

The result of the `mapStateToProps` function is a plain object, but this object is NOT being merged into the child component props - this is illustrated by this screen shot:

[image: disconnect between value in mapStateToProps and the component's props]

Here is the code to show that I `console.log(props.timeslipInModal)`, which is non-false in the console but the props of the wrapped component does not change.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let props = {
        userIdBy: false,
        apiToken: false
    };
    props.timeslipInModal = state.timeslipInModal ? state.timeslipInModal : false;
    if (state && state.myBus) {
        if (state.myBus.payrun) {
            // state.myBus.payrun.loading, loaded and errors copied by this
            props = Object.assign(state.myBus.payrun, props);
        }
        if (state.myBus.common && state.myBus.common.auth) {
            props.userIdBy = state.myBus.common.auth.userId;
            props.apiToken = state.myBus.common.auth.apiToken;
        }
    }
    console.log('timeslipInModal at the end of mapStateToProps:', props.timeslipInModal);
    return props;
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    dispatch,
    fetchPayrunDetails:
        dispatch(fetchPayrunDetails(ownProps.userIdBy, ownProps.apiToken, ownProps.entityId))
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(OnePayrunGridContainer);
```

---

My Reducer for the `fetchPayrunDetails` looks like this:

```js
case 'FETCH_PAYRUN_TS_DETAILS_FULFILLED': {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    newState.myBus = Object.assign({}, state.myBus);
    newState.myBus.payrun = action.payload.data.data;
    newState.myBus.payrun.loading = false;
    newState.myBus.payrun.loaded = true;
    newState.myBus.payrun.errors = false;
    return newState;
}
```

My Reducer to update the `reactStore.timeslipInModal` is a separate case in the `reducer.js`:

```js
case 'FETCH_TIMESLIP_DATA_FULFILLED': {
    if (action.payload.data.errors) {
        // caputure errors - not relevant here
    }
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state, {
        modalFetchErrors: false,
        modalFetched: true,
        modalFetching: false,
        modalValidating: false,
        timeslipInModal: action.payload.data.timeslip
    });
    return newState;
}
```

---

One thing that is a little 'different' and hence may be a problem - in my `entry.js` script, I have a loop where I look for html entities by their ID, and based on their id, I call the correct component to render.

This allows me to have one `entry.js` script called at the end of my common template view.

```js
import OnePayrunGridContainer from './components/payrun/OnePayrunGridContainer.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store.js';
// put these in here so they match code searches - these container components
// are included below by Alias so explicitly list them here: <OnePayrunGridContainer>
let componentNamesByRootElementIds = {
    onePayrunGridMyBus: OnePayrunGridContainer
};
let htmlElement = false;
for (let onereactElementId in componentNamesByRootElementIds) {
    htmlElement = document.getElementById(onereactElementId);
    if (htmlElement) {
        let Component = componentNamesByRootElementIds[onereactElementId];
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component
                    userIdBy={userIdBy}
                    apiToken={apiToken}
                    entityId={entityId}
                    onereactElementId={onereactElementId}
                />
            </Provider>,
            htmlElement
        );
    }
}
```

Also, I do export the `connect` in my `OnePayrunGridContainer.js`:

```js
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(OnePayrunGridContainer)
```

The other props all update when the `FETCH_PAYRUN_TS_DETAILS_FULFILLED` calls are made that update the redux store - what am I missing? How do I make the props on the wrapped component update **correctly** when the redux state is updated by the `FETCH_TIMESLIP_DATA_FULFILLED` action?

Comment: show us `fetchPayrunDetails` implementation

Comment: @Justcode - I added in the reducer code. The action fetchPayrunDetails calls a Axios Promise that calls a PHP API, so I just show the reducer here. I hope it is something as obvious as lack of immutabiity

Comment: Does your component update when your state changed? Can you create stackblitz link to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Where does `timeslipInModal` get updated? Because, in the reducer case that you have shown, it doesn't seem that `timeslipInModal` gets updated (maybe it is a part of the `action.payload.data`, however, we can't figure that out from the reducer.

Also, this might be nitpicking, but, `timeslipInModal` has initial value - `false`, and  is then assigned an `Object`?

Comment: One more thing, we usually return the `State-To-Prop` as is from the reducer, and do whatever change that we want in either the `reducer` or the `action-creator`.

For. e.g: `mapStateToProps` should be as simple as -

```js
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            userIdBy: state.userIdBy,
            apiToken: state.apiToken,
            timeslipInModal: state.timeslipInModal
        };
    }
```

Comment: I added the code for the reducer case that updates timeslipInModal: action.payload.data.timeslip to answer @yadav_vi 's question.

Comment: @yadav_vi: Regarding returning the State-To-Prop 'as-is' from the reducer, I agree that is a good way to go. However, I am merging in two reducer cases here, as I re-use the 'FETCH_TIMESLIP_DATA' reducer case in a few other places. I chose to complicate the mapStateToProp instead of duplicating the FETCH_TIMESLIP_DATA reducer code.

Comment: There is only 2 things that I think might go wrong - 1) You are NOT passing `timeslipInModal` as a prop to your `Component`. 2) Some error in `connect` - Ideally, the component that you export using `connect` is a Container Component. So, this should instead have been - `export default connect(...)(OnePayrunGridComponent);`

Comment: @yadav_vi I have added in my code to demonstrate how I 1) export connect(...) and 2) call ReactDOM.render() in a loop (which is not the straight forward way to do it so may be a cause)

Comment: Please post a working example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's going to take me a few hours to cut this code down to a minimum working example - I will do that in January - thanks for your help so far. Hopefully I will find the problem while cutting the code down to a minimum. I will post the answer if I do.